# How to get permission's role with seam

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, seam

I need in my application to get all permissions associated with a specific role with seam ?

I tried with `permissionManager.listPermissions` but this method gives permissions associated with a specific target and not a specific recipient (role in my case).

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

this is not possible by default in Seam. However, you can extend your permission store to do this. If you are using the JpaPermissionStore (which in most of the cases is true), you can check [this link](https://sites.google.com/a/softwarefactory.co.nz/seam-tips/security-and-permissions/extending-jpapermissionstore)